# Excel 2010 Worksheet_Deactivate() auto sort

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm a VBA noob. I'm trying to get a page to auto sort whenever I leave that page. The page has six manual sorts for various columns, but needs to be alpha by the first column for a lookup on another page. So when the user manually sorts by another field, I want it to revert back to the needed column sort when leaving the page. I've tried about six different macros that I've found and threw a couple edits into them, but none of them seems to do anything. Here's my latest attempt:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

    With Me.Range("B6:K604").CurrentRegion
        .Sort Key1:=Range("B6:B604"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does each sheet utilize the same range and sort parameters?

Comment: Try replacing **me** with the actual sheet reference

Comment: Tried it with both Sheet3 and Worksheet("Aircraft") - no change.

Comment: I did get this to work: `code` Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Worksheets("Aircraft").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets("Aircraft").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B5:B604"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets("Aircraft").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B5:J604")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    SendKeys "{ESC}"
End Sub `code` but it leaves the range selected and causes weird visual effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Dim sortkey As Range, sortrng As Range

With me
    Set sortkey = .Range("B6:B604")
    Set sortrng = .Range("B6:K604")
End With

me.Sort.SortFields.Clear
me.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sortkey, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With me.Sort
    .SetRange sortrng
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlSortColumns
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Ok this is **tried and tested**.
The key is to clear existing filters first.

Comment: I'm going to try this to see if the results are better than with my current code. Thanks.

Comment: That works too, but still leaves an odd boxed background on the newly selected page.

Comment: Turns out all I have to do to the above code is turn off screen updating during the deactivate sort and the visual corruption disappears. Thanks a lot for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Put in another event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C9").CurrentRegion
    .Sort Key1:=Range("B6:B604"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
End Sub
```

active the sheet, sort and save...